# Compressing two Python try/except blocks into one without changing behavior

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

I am working on a patch for an existing bug in error handling in the standard library's `shutil.rmtree()` and I encountered this code:

```
try:
    orig_st = os.lstat(path)
except Exception:
    onerror(os.lstat, path, sys.exc_info())
    return
try:
    fd = os.open(path, os.O_RDONLY)
except Exception:
    onerror(os.lstat, path, sys.exc_info())
    return
```

I would like to simplify it to the following before applying my changes to ease implementation:

```
try:
    orig_st = os.lstat(path)
    fd = os.open(path, os.O_RDONLY)
except Exception:
    onerror(os.lstat, path, sys.exc_info())
    return
```

Is there any case in which behavior would be different between the two code samples?

Comment: Don't catch `Exception`. Catch specific exceptions instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know that's best practice, but unfortunately I cannot break backwards compatibility in the `shutils.rmtree` API and therefore I must maintain the current handling of `onerror` until the feature is deprecated and removed.  (The messiness and complexity of the `onerror` system is in fact what we're trying to fix with this patch, but it will be a multistep process.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

there is no case in a single threaded application where the two are different. In a multithreaded application the "path" could change between the two try excepts, though.

This code was introduced in a patch fixing a symlink attack vulnerability (http://bugs.python.org/issue4489). Maybe you should ask the original committer for a code review after your changes. According to http://hg.python.org/cpython/annotate/c910af2e3c98/Lib/shutil.py#434 , it is Hynek Schlawack .

Comment: Thank you. I am at the PyCon sprint right now, and either the bug author is actually here, or I can consult another core dev about the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

I think the two cases are identical, but only because there is a `return` inside each of the exception blocks, meaning that the second `try...except` block doesn't actually get executed if an exception is encountered in the first.

If the first `try...except` didn't `return`, then the second `try...except` block would be executed even if an exception was encountered in the first block, and the two cases would not be identical.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason they have it split, is because if it catches Exception on the first try, then it will then still do set a value to fd. The way you have it written, if the Exception is caught on the first bit of code (i.e. orig_st) then it will never set fd because it will already have passed it, even though it may not contain the Exception.

Comment: But the `return` in the exception block would prevent the second block from happening anyway. I think the two cases are equivalent so long as each block `return`s on exception.

Comment: oops, didn't see the returns.